# How do I get an enum element's numerical value using libclang?

Tags: c++, enums, libclang

Suppose I have an enum definition, e.g.:

```
// myenum.h
enum MyEnum {
    First = 1,
    Second,
    Third,
    TwoAgain = Second
};
```

I would like to **programmatically generate a map from any given enum definition, where the key is the enum element's name, and the value is the enum element's numerical value** (e.g. `myMap["TwoAgain"] == 2`)

So far, I know how to traverse the source file using `clang_visitChildren()`, and extract individual tokens using `clang_tokenize()`. Recursing through the AST, I get cursors/tokens in this order:

1. "MyEnum" (CXType_Enum)

   - "First" (CXToken_Identifier)
   - "=" (CXToken_Punctuation)
   - "1" (CXToken_Literal)
2. "unsigned int" (CXType_UInt)

   - "1" (CXToken_Literal)
3. "MyEnum" (CXType_Enum)

   - "Second" (CXToken_Identifier)
4. "MyEnum" (CXType_Enum)

   - "Third" (CXToken_Identifier)
5. "MyEnum" (CXType_Enum)

   - "TwoAgain" (CXToken_Identifier)
   - "=" (CXToken_Punctuation)
   - "Second" (CXToken_Identifier)
6. "unsigned int" (CXType_UInt)

   - "Second" (CXToken_Identifier)

I guess I could write an algorithm that uses this information to calculate every value. However, I was wondering if there's a simpler way? **Can I get the numerical values directly from the libclang API?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

libclang exposes this information through [`clang_getEnumConstantDeclValue`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TYPES.html#ga6b8585818420e7512feb4c9d209b4f4d) and [`clang_getEnumConstantDeclUnsignedValue`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TYPES.html#gaf7cbd4f2d371dd93e8bc997c951a1aef). A map like you describe can be built by visiting the children of a `CXCursor_EnumDecl`:

```
static enum CXChildVisitResult VisitCursor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data) {
    if (cursor.kind == CXCursor_EnumConstantDecl) {
        CXString spelling = clang_getCursorSpelling(cursor);
        myMap[clang_getCString(spelling)] = clang_getEnumConstantDeclValue(cursor);
        clang_disposeString(spelling);
    }

    return CXChildVisit_Continue;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, @MattStevens; thank you! We really can't get any simpler and cleaner than this. I was trying to work with CXTypeKind, but I had somehow missed CXCursorKind.

Answer (score 1):

As id256 said, I don't think you can do this with `libclang`. However, Clang's [`libtooling` and plugin interface](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) allow you to access the AST and operate on that directly. For enums, you'll want to look at the `EnumDecl` class, which allows you to iterate over the inner decls. Then it's just a case of building up a map like:

```
for (auto declIterator = myEnumDecl.decls_begin();
     declIterator != myEnumDecl.decls_end();
     ++declIterator)
{
    myMap[declIterator->getNameAsString()] = declIterator->getInitVal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solution, @TartanLlama! I half-suspected this is out of scope for `libclang`, but it's good to have confirmation and the alternative.

Comment: Actually, it is possible through `libclang`. See @MattStevens' answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way in get name and value for your map. i am using clang 8.

```
bool VisitEnumDecl(EnumDecl *ED)
      {

        for (auto it = ED->enumerator_begin(); it != ED->enumerator_end(); it++)
        {


         std::cout <<it->getNameAsString()<<" "<<it->getInitVal().getSExtValue()<<std::endl;


        }
        return true;
      }
```